# python-ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am getting error in following lines. error is not recurring but only sometimes

```
x,y are huge numbers of 2048 bits
z=bin(x)+bin(y)
z=int(z,2)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '10010101101001011011000000001111001110111110000100101000000011111111100000111010111011101111110010001101101001101000100000001100010011000010100000110100100001010110011111101101000101101001011001100110'
```

Comment: I suspect that the `ValueError` does not come from the code you've posted, since the string should contain two `"b"` characters, as Jochen has pointed out in his answer.

Comment: Did you really get that _exact_ error message? Which version of Python? Which OS?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you haven't faked that error message?

The code...

```
>>> int('10010101101001011011000000001111001110111110000100101000000011111111100000111010111011101111110010001101101001101000100000001100010011000010100000110100100001010110011111101101000101101001011001100110', 2)
939350809951131205472627037306557272273273866819979105965670L
```

...works for me.

And, a concrete example of your code...

```
>>> x = 82349832
>>> y = 23432984
>>> z = bin(x) + bin(y)
>>> int(z, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '0b1001110100010001111000010000b1011001011000111100011000'
```

...shows the problem (i.e. the `0b` prefixes) in the error message.

The solution would be to either strip the prefixes with...

```
z = bin(x)[2:] + bin(y)[2:]
z = int(z, 2)
```

...or, as Martijn Pieters suggests, generate the binary representation without prefixes using `format()`...

```
z = format(x, 'b') + format(y, 'b')
z = int(z, 2)
```

...or, as gnibbler suggests, use the string object's `format()` method to do it in one call...

```
z = '{:b}{:b}'.format(x, y)
z = int(z, 2)
```

Comment: Or use `format(x, 'b')` and get a binary representation *without* the `0b` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

`bin` gives you a string representation so `bin( .. ) + bin( .. )` concats two string, which is not a valid result.

```
>>> bin(0) + bin(1)
'0b00b1'
```

In case you are trying to work with actual binary data (not string representations of integer representation of binary data, which is what your code does) then you should use the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

[bin](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) will return string in format:

```
'0b1100000011001011101000111010110011'
```

With first `'0b'`

So, for you code, you can use this (will sum `x` and `y` as integers):

```
z=int(bin(x)[2:], 2) + int(bin(y)[2:], 2)
```

Or, if you want exactly first to concatinate the `x` and `y` as strings:

```
z=bin(x)[2:]+bin(y)[2:]
z=int(z,2)
```

Comment: after this line `z=bin(x)[2:]+bin(y)[2:]`, `z` will be a string, that contains only "0" and "1". Are you sure, you've executed this line `z=bin(x)[2:]+bin(y)[2:]` before `z=int(z,2)` ?

Comment: yes i did but it is giving error only sometimes, rest it is working fine... so 8 out of 10 are working fine.

Comment: Check you input values `x` and `y`. Maybe they have some bad values. Or maybe error occurs in another peace of code.

Comment: according to the error, z is taking string of '0' and '1' but it is having problem in converting it back to int.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the inbuild sqrt function was not working for my python 2.7.2 Ubuntu 12.04. So I used user defined function for square root. thanks everyone for help.

```
def ceilofsqrt(N):
    answerlower = 1
    answerupper = N
    while answerupper - answerlower  > 2:
        answerupper = (answerupper + answerlower)/2 + (answerupper + answerlower)%2
        answerlower = N/answerupper
    guess = answerlower
    while True:    
        if guess**2 >= N:
            return guess
        guess += 1
```